# Firewall policies

Tags: firewall, juniper

I have a Juniper 5GT firewall that I use for my home server, On my home server I have an SSH server running, I am trying to access the SSH from the untrust side of the firewall, from what I believe this requires a policy to be setup and I have done so:

Untrust --> Trust - Service: SSH, Source: Any, Destination: Any

Trust --> Untrust - Service: SSH, Source: Any, Destination: Any

When I go into putty, i enter the IP of the firewall, however all I get is a timeout error. Can anybody help? I am sure i am making a rookie mistake! 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that product, but does it know where to route inbound SSH packets?

Answer (score 0):

You need more than that, you need to configure destination address translation or port forwarding

For example

```
Your router public IP is  : A.B.C.D
Your router private IP is : 192.168.1.1
Your ssh server IP is     : 192.168.1.2
```

Then you need to setup DNAT so any packet arrived A.B.C.D:22 will have destination IP translated to 192.168.1.2 and forwared to your SSH server.

Do some search on port forwarding, it is easy to setup.